# How to prevent ReweiteRules to match subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I limit my `mod_rewrite` RewriteRules to only apply to the *www* and *no-subdomain*?

The subdomains are in different folders -- rather website root folder, however all of my RewirteRules apply to all of the subdomains, which is not what I want.

I know that it's possible to match every RewriteRule by a RewriteCond that only matches *www* and *no-subdomain*, but then I have to repeat the same thing for all the RewriteRules, which is not what I want again.

So I was wondering if there is any way to *globally* prevent RewriteRules to apply to other subdomains? I can also place `.htaccess` files in each subdomain as well to prevent matching, if that's a possibility.

Here is part of what I have in `.htaccess` right now:

```
options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^city/([^/].+)/([^/].+)/([^/].+)/$ index.php?page=$3&city=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^city/([^/].+)/([^/].+)/$ index.php?city=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^flights/([^/].+)/$ index.php?page=flights&mode=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^health/([^/].+)/$ index.php?page=health&view=$1 [L]
# so on ...
RewriteRule ^([^/].+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**Update #1**

Just to explain the problem better, right now `sub.domain.com` shows `domain.com` instead of it's actual content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert this single rule below `RewriteBase` line to ignore all sub-domains from rest of the rules:

```
# ignore all sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Replace `example.com` with your actual domain.

Comment: I did, but now it _redirects_ every request to `example.com`. None of the rules work.

Comment: Well, I know that this doesn't redirect explicitly, but I'm explaining the effect. The exclamation mark is there.

Comment: Also please take a look at my update. Right now the sub-domains shows the `www` content and I don't have access to Apache configuration. Would it be caused by something else rather `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Strangely, with your suggested edit it does redirect, however with my original rules, it just shows the content, without a hard redirect.

Comment: Repeating once again, this suggested rule cannot do any redirect/rewrite as meaning of `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` is to **"just do nothing"**

Comment: I know and I'm just explaining the effect. Let me see if I can spot anything somewhere else. Thanks for the efforts, tho, I will upvote :)

Comment: It seems that it is Apache missconfiguration. Thanks for the effort again. I at least learnd one new mod_rewrite trick!